# Spring WS endpoint routing when whole body is encrypted

Tags: web-services, soap, spring-boot, spring-ws

So I'm working with Spring Boot to implement a service API for interop with a third party.  I'm using payload-based routing because they are not sending SOAPAction or any addressing information.  However, when a request comes in, it's trying to map one of the incoming encryption-related elements and failing to map.  I think the problem is that my friends at the third party are element-encrypting the operation element:

```
<n1:body>
  <n2:SomeOperation>       // This is
    ...some content...     // all
  </n3:SomeOperation>      // encrypted
</n1:body>
```

From my reading, Spring attempts to map to an endpoint before encryption, so payload mapping will never work.  I could use @Action or @SoapAction, but they are using Soap 1.2 (so no action header) and not using addressing.  I have also verified that the Wss4SecurityInterceptor is being added, but is never called when a request is made.

Is my assessment/understanding of the situation correct?  Can anyone think of any workarounds, because having the remote party change anything is nearly impossible.

A related question (hopefully asking one is not too unorthodox): I was trying to make my test client only encrypt the content of my operation element, but my `setSecurementEncryptionParts()` call is not playing nice.  Here's the outgoing payload(from the console):

```
<ns2:EchoTestInput xmlns:ns2="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/EchoTestSchema">
  <ns2:valueIn>Quack</ns2:valueIn>
</ns2:EchoTestInput>
```

And here's the call to `setSecurementEncryptionParts()`

```
securityInterceptor.setSecurementEncryptionParts("{Content}{http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/EchoTestSchema}EchoTestInput");
```

I thought this should all be easy, but I guess not.  Thanks a million in advance!